# django userform not showing in HTML page

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am new to django . here I want to register user and I have a problem , the user form doesnt show in registration html page

here is my code:

views.py :

```
enter code here
 from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
 from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
 from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
 from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
 from django.views import generic
 from django.views.generic import View
 from .forms import UserForm
 from .models import Album


class UserFormView(View):
   form_class = UserForm
   template_name = 'music/registration_form.html'

# display blank form

def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():

        user = form.save(commit=False)

        # cleaned (Normalized) data
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

# return user objects if info r correct

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:

            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('music:index')

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

form.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
```

I think there is nothing wrong with url.py as long as the page pops up, I dunno where I'm mistaken

Comment: Are your get and post methods correctly indented in your code? In your code above they are sitting outside the class. Not sure if that happened when you asked the question or if that's where you actually have them.

Comment: `the user form doesnt show in registration html page` what does that mean?